Cannot find module 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls' or its corresponding type declarations
I'm using TypeScript and three.js in my React project, and I'm importing OrbitControls like so:
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

But I'm getting the following highlighted error for the OrbitControls import:

Cannot find module 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls' or its corresponding type declarations.

This error appeared after I switched to TypeScript. I've installed three using npm install three and also did npm install --save-dev @types/three, so I'm not sure why I'm still getting an error about a type declaration. How do I get rid of this error?

According to the docs, you need to add a .js to the import, like so:
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

This should get rid of the error for you.
